# Django static css doesn't make any change and images don't appear

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

Django static files are not working in my application, I defined `STATICFILES_DIRS`, `STATIC_URL`, and `STATIC_ROOT` in settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'social_media')
]
```

and here's base.html:

```
{% load static %}
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type= "text/css" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block navbar %}
        {% include 'parts/navbar.html' %}
        {% endblock %}
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

I use this in my pages:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<!--stuff-->
{% endblock content %}
```

directory:

[image: directory]

I tried using InPrivate(incognito but MS Edge version) window and nothing changed, I also tried deleting style.css file and making it again and collecting static files again but it also didn't work.

Comment: Have you also made changes in urls.py?

Comment: `urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)`

Comment: @SunderamDubey didn't work

Comment: You should now restart your server in another port using `python manage.py runserver 5000` and hard refresh using Ctrl+f5  with the above changes in urls.py.

Comment: @SunderamDubey uhh, still didn't work.

Comment: What is `social_media`, shouldn't this be `static`.

Comment: @SunderamDubey that's the project's name, when I put static it shows me this error:
(staticfiles.E002) The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting.

Comment: What is the directory structure under the app where `style.css` is located before you run `collectstatic`?

Comment: @michjnich https://imgur.com/a/ojiJcrs

Comment: That doesn't show me where your css file is. Can you update the question with the directory structure and indicate where you have put it.

Comment: First things first: what _does not work_ means? 404? Please open rendered page, use "Inspect elements", grab css file url and open it in a separate tab. What's the error message?

Answer (score 0):

***Make the Following changes as mentioned and try again it will definitely solve your problem.***

1. Static Files Dir: @settings.py

   ```
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
       os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media")
   ```
2. Static files url : @root_urls.py

   ```
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    from django.conf import settings         
    urlpatterns = [...] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
   ```

Comment: It shows up this error:
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.

Comment: try to run "python manage.py collectstatic"