# Django navbar css doesn't make any changes

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

It's probably not about static files configuration because images work and CSS other than navbar's work, navbar's CSS doesn't make any changes it's just like it's not there, even though when I tried to make a simple h1 and color it (as a test) it worked, it's just the navbar's CSS for some reason that I really can't figure out.

base.html:

```
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
  </head>
  <body>
    {% block navbar %}
    {% include 'parts/navbar.html' %}
    {% endblock navbar %}
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}
  </body>
</html>
```

homepage.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}
```

navbar.html:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}" />
</head>
<div class="navContainer">
  <div class="navbar">
    <img src="{% static 'images/navLogo.png' %}" class="logo" />
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Projects</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

static configuration in settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
]
```

app's urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.homepage, name="homepage")
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

what I'm getting:

[image: result]

perhaps this directory image could help too:

[image]

Comment: What the point of starting new thread instead of replying in the old one? Questions to the OP would be the same.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74255702/django-static-css-doesnt-make-any-change-and-images-dont-appear

Comment: What happens when you open manually your css file url?

Comment: @IvanStarostin this is a different project and the problem is different I thought like this.

Comment: @IvanStarostin It's probably not a css link thing because I tried to color a `h1` as a test and it worked

Comment: Try to add navbar container inside body tag and try